# function keys jsch (Java)

Tags: java, jsch

I use jsch for connect to a router Cisco and execute somme commands. But in some cases it ask me to press function keys as F1, F2...

I want to know if this is possible and how?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) and [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html). The second class has static int fields representing almost every key on the keyboard. F1 is VK_F1, F2 is VK_2 ... and so on.
To send a 'F1' key stroke use this :

```
Robot robot = new Robot(); 
robot.keyPress(VK_F1);
```